# Android 4.4 SMS - Not receiving sentIntents

Tags: android

I have an Sms application that works fine in older versions of Android. In 4.4 when I send messages through

```
 smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(dest, serviceCenter, messages, sentIntents, null);
```

(http://goo.gl/e7VW4)

The *sentIntents* are actually never sent, giving me no information on whether the sms was sent or the reason that it failed. This detected this on a Nexus 5 with 4.4. Though it works in a Galaxy Nexus with 4.3.

**Update #1**: This situation occurs *only* when sending SMS to invalid numbers. I want to receive the *sentIntent* to update the UI.

Has any one had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.4 introduced the concept of a [default SMS app](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#SMS) (as explained in this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)) - only the default SMS app can send SMS messages - all other apps will silently fail.

Comment: Please read the update. I have it working with 4.4 when the destination is a valid number. However what I describe only occurs when there's invalid characters in the destination or the destination string size is incorrect.